# how to take custom amount of data from foreach loop php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreach, laravel-5.8

So in Eloquent there is a `take()` and `skip()` functions works like this:

`$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();`

But now I'm reading data from a json file:

```
$path = storage_path() . "/app/public/userexam.json";    

json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
```

So after reading data, I want to use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($json as $js){
   ...
}
```

But I do need to take custom amount of records of `$json`.

Something like this:

```
foreach($json->take(5) as $js){
...
}
```

But this thing obviously does not work and returns **`Call to a member function take() on array`**.

So how can I use **take** and **skip** eloquent functions in a foreach loop in this case (or something equivalent to them).

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) on the JSON array to implement `skip` and  `take`. For example:

```php
$skip = 10;
$take = 5;
foreach (array_slice($json, $skip, $take) as $js) {
    // ... do what is necessary on the data
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mluvJ)

Comment: What happened to your `break`?  I was going to say if $take=5 then 6 records would have been taken.

Comment: @Misunderstood that was a brain fade... :-P

Answer (score 2):

You might need **collect()** method as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-collect).

> collect(json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true));

After that you might able to use **take()** or **skip()** method.